# Is there a way to determine whether an instagram account is private/public/ business using the instagram graph api?

Tags: api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to find a way to check if the list of usernames are private or public
Is there a specific way to determine it if I have the userid of the instagram id?
I'm using Instagram Graph API

Answer (score -3):

This is a nice explanation, guide for this task: [instagram privacy setting](https://www.guidingtech.com/instagram-privacy-settings/).

On the desktop web page.

1. Click on Your user icon.
2. In the dropdown menu click on profile.
3. In the profile settings click on privacy and security.
4. On the page for the settings privacy and security Private account.

Checked in private account, unchecked is public account.

I hope that helped. Please make an arrow up for my answer.